# The client_secret provided does not match the client_secret associated with the PaymentIntent

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PaymentData {
  static Future<void> makePayment() async {
    Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntentData;
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'firebase function url');
    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    paymentIntentData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(paymentIntentData);
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['paymentIntent'],
      applePay: true,
      googlePay: true,
      style: ThemeMode.system,
      merchantCountryCode: 'US',
      merchantDisplayName: 'Raja',
    ));
    //displayPaymentSheet(paymentIntentData);
  }

  static Future<void> displayPaymentSheet(
      Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntentData) async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
          parameters: PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
              clientSecret: paymentIntentData!['paymentIntent'],
              confirmPayment: true));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

> I am getting the same error, This is my code, I've tried many other logic but facing the same error.I have used the the flutter dependency **flutter_stripe**. I've created the Firebase function and also tried without using Firebase.

Comment: I think the variable for your `paymentIntentClientSecret` parameter is wrong: ```paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret']```